# Extract a single struct from a Matlab struct of arrays

Tags: matlab, struct

Suppose I'm given a struct of arrays, e.g.:

```
s = 

foo: [3x3 double]
bar: [3x1 double]
```

Is there an easy way to extract a struct with the same field names as `s` and with each field populated by the `ix`th row of the same field in `s`?  I can assume that every field has the same number of rows.  Given the above, I could do

```
ix = 1;
s1.foo = s.foo(ix, :);
s1.bar = s.bar(ix, :);
```

But if s has more than a couple fields, this gets unwieldy.  Is there a function that would do the equivalent, a la `s1 = extractstruct(s, ix)`?

Comment: In fact, it would be sweet to have a function `fieldfun`

Comment: @Oli, try [`structfun`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/structfun.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It s not as short as `s1 = extractstruct(s, ix)`, but I would do that:

```
s.foo = rand(3);
s.bar = rand(1,3);
xi=1;

s2=reshape([fieldnames(s)'; cellfun(@(x) x(xi,:),struct2cell(s)','UniformOutput',0)],1,[]);
s2=struct(s2{:})


s2 = 

    foo: [0.8147 0.9134 0.2785]
    bar: [0.7922 0.9595 0.6557]
```

Comment: Should 'Un)],1,[]iformOutput' be 'UniformOutput'?

Comment: Also, to be exactly my problem, it should be `s.bar = rand(3,1)` so that it has the same number of rows.  /nitpicky

Comment: This would be better with `cell2struct` rather than `struct`.